# virtualbox and python API

Tags: python, xpcom

0  vote down

I have installed virtualbox . but i cant import the module xpcom. but the synaptic package shows that it is installed. what could be wrong?

-ASK

Answer (score 1):

To be able to import xpcom, you would need to install [pyxpcom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/PyXPCOM) extension, and build instructions are [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Building_PyXPCOM).

In Synaptic Package Manager, it would be [`python-xpcom`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/intrepid-updates/python-xpcom)